# seeking help for Object Clone

Tags: c#

```
class Puzzle
{
    public int PUZZLESIZE = 3;
    public int numSteps = 0;
    public Button[,] buttons;

    public Puzzle(Form1 form1)
    {
        buttons = new Button[3, 3] { { form1.button1, form1.button2, form1.button3 }, 
                                     { form1.button4, form1.button5, form1.button6 }, 
                                     { form1.button7, form1.button8, form1.button9 } };
    }

    public Puzzle Clone()
    {
        return (Puzzle)this.MemberwiseClone();           
    }

    public void reset()
    {
        //reset all 9 buttons color
    }

    public void flipcells()
    {
        //flip cells in the puzzle with color change
    }

class Undo
{
    Puzzle newPuzzle; //null value here. Why??? 

    public Undo(Puzzle oldPuzzle) 
    {
        Puzzle newPuzzle = oldPuzzle.Clone();
    }               

    public void undo()
    {
       //back to previous step, ie the color of the buttons go back to previous color
    }
```

I'm asking to do the undo function for back to previous stages for max four times. "The easiest way to do this is to create a copy of the puzzle and store it in an array of Puzzle. To do this I implemented a Clone method for puzzle. This returns a brand new puzzle set to exactly the same settings as the puzzle that I called Clone on." This is what our instructor says, but i still have no idea of how to implement this.

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to implement your "Undo" function would probably be with a stack. For each action you take on the puzzle, push an instance onto the stack. When the user opts to undo a move, pop the instance off of the stack.

See [this article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) for more information on stacks, and [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx) on the .NET Stack generic class.

Comment: Do I declare stack in undo class???

Comment: Think of the stack as your Undo class. Its job will be to hold the previous state of the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little example of how to implement the stack mentioned by DBM.  In stead of cloning the whole Puzzle class, I would recommend to rather just clone the array of Buttons (that should be enough for your Undo function):

**Edit:** If you need to keep track of the colors of the buttons in stead of the position of the buttons, you could probably rather just put an array of the buttons' current colors on the stack.

```
    Stack<Button[,]> stack = new Stack<Button[,]>();

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button[,] buttons = new Button[2, 2] { { button1, button2 }, { button3, button4 } };
        stack.Push((Button[,])buttons.Clone());
        buttons[0, 0] = button2;
        buttons[0, 1] = button1;
        stack.Push((Button[,])buttons.Clone());
        buttons[1, 0] = button4;
        buttons[1, 1] = button3;
        stack.Push((Button[,])buttons.Clone());
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            Button[,] buttons = stack.Pop();
            txtButtonOrder.Text = buttons[0, 0].Text + buttons[0, 1].Text + buttons[1, 0].Text + buttons[1, 1].Text;
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable inside a method, it will hide any variables in the class which have the same name.  Instead of redeclaring the variable, you should just reference it:

```
int myVariable = 0; // Will always be 0

public void SetMyVariable()
{
    int myVariable = 5; // Isn't the same as above
}
```

If you want to be explicit, you can add 'this.' in front of the variable name to always refer to the class variable:

```
this.myVariable = 5;
```